# OpenAI API "AuthenticationError No API key provided" when switching to internalConsole in VS Code launch.json

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, openai-api

I'm using the OpenAI API in a Python script and have set the OPENAI_API_KEY as an environment variable in my system, which works fine when running the script in the integrated terminal. What I have used to set the key.
https://help.openai.com/en/articles/5112595-best-practices-for-api-key-safety

However, when I change the debugging configuration in my launch.json file from "console": "integratedTerminal" to "console": "internalConsole", the API key is not recognized, and I get an AuthenticationError.

How can I properly set the API key when using the "internalConsole" configuration in VS Code so that the OpenAI API works correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the OpenAI API key when using the "internalConsole" configuration in VS Code, you can create a separate secrets.json file containing your API key, and then load the key in your Python script directly to openai object.

1. Create a secrets.json file in your project folder with your API key:

```
    {
        "OPENAI_API_KEY": "your-api-key-here"
    }
```

Replace "your-api-key-here" with your actual OpenAI API key.

2. Add the secrets.json file to your .gitignore file to prevent it from being accidentally committed to your Git repository:

```
    # .gitignore
    secrets.json
```

3. In your main Python script, create a function to load the API key from the secrets.json file and use it to set the api_key of the OpenAI library:

   ```
   import json
   import openai

   def load_api_key(secrets_file="secrets.json"):
       with open(secrets_file) as f:
           secrets = json.load(f)
       return secrets["OPENAI_API_KEY"]

   # Set secret API key
   # Typically, we'd use an environment variable (e.g., echo "export OPENAI_API_KEY='yourkey'" >> ~/.zshrc)
   # However, using "internalConsole" in launch.json requires setting it in the code for compatibility with Hebrew
   api_key = load_api_key()
   openai.api_key = api_key

   # Your script's content goes here
   ```

By following these steps, your API key will be properly set when using the "internalConsole" configuration in VS Code, and your OpenAI API calls should work as expected.